# Get HTML source code of table with specific attribute

Tags: c#, html, http, uwp, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get the HTML source code of a table with a specific attribute.
The code below will help you understand more.

```
public static async Task GetCldInfos()
{
    string sURL = @"https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/";
    using (HttpClient clientduplicate = new HttpClient())
    {
        clientduplicate.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident / 6.0)");

        using (HttpResponseMessage responseduplicate = await clientduplicate.GetAsync(sURL))
        using (HttpContent contentduplicate = responseduplicate.Content)
        {
            try
            {
                string resultduplicate = await contentduplicate.ReadAsStringAsync();

                //var websiteduplicate = new HtmlDocument();
                //websiteduplicate.LoadHtml(resultduplicate);
                Debug.WriteLine(resultduplicate);
            }
            catch (Exception ex1)
            {
                throw ex1.InnerException;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When we visit [here](https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/) we have an option to set the time frame.
The timeframe we chose modifies the table accordingly. 
When I do an http request to get the source it automatically gives me the standard GMT which is GMT -5:00.

How can I get the source for example with GMT 0:00?

Comment: As I told you in a previous question, Agility Pack can't run Javascript, and there is no way to fetch any data other than the default that HTTP single call HTML returns. In order to do that, you need a headless browser or the `WebView` as we have used in the last answer. Consider using *Awesomium* (http://www.awesomium.com/). It's free and has some nice utilities for headless browsing, like a `WebView` standalone class.

Answer (score 0):

With HTML Agility Pack, you can use the following extension method to get a specific element with a specific attribute:

```
    public static IEnumerable<HtmlNode> GetNodesByAttr(this HtmlDocument htmlDoc, string tag, string attributeName, string attributeValue)
    {
        var allTags = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants(tag);

        return (from htmlNode in allTags
                select htmlNode.Attributes
                    into attrs
                    from attr in attrs
                    where attr.Name == attributeName && attr.Value == attributeValue
                    select attr).Select(attr => attr.OwnerNode).ToList();

    }
```

For example, if you want to find **table** with **class** **"gmt0"**, you can call the extension method like this:

```
var websiteduplicate = new HtmlDocument();
websiteduplicate.LoadHtml(resultduplicate);

var myElement = websiteduplicate.GetNodesByAttr("table", "class", "gmt0").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I don't think that is the correct answer. The table with the requested GMT time is not available. The only one available is the standard one, GMT -5:00.
Apparently there is a header that must be set before the request is made. I am still trying to figure out what though.

Comment: Ah, in that case you have to use something like Fiddler or Chrome's network tools to figure what happens when you change the combobox selection. The above code is for getting the HTML source of specific element.