# Get div class height

Tags: c#, css, uwp, html-agility-pack

Is there a way to get a `class` 's height on `C#`?
I am using `HTMLAgilitPack` to get the nodes. Here is my code.

```
private async void GetCldInfos()
    {
        string sURL = @"https://m.investing.com/economic-calendar/";
        using (HttpClient clientduplicate = new HttpClient())
        {
            clientduplicate.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident / 6.0)");

            using (HttpResponseMessage responseduplicate = await clientduplicate.GetAsync(sURL))
            using (HttpContent contentduplicate = responseduplicate.Content)
            {
                try
                {
                    string resultduplicate = await contentduplicate.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    var websiteduplicate = new HtmlDocument();
                    websiteduplicate.LoadHtml(resultduplicate);
                    var News = websiteduplicate.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(o => o.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "js-economic-calendar").Single();
                    //get height here
                }
                catch (Exception ex1)
                {
                    throw ex1.InnerException;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: here is an image: [image: here]
In the image I can seem to find it's height. Is there a way to get that height programmatically?
I want to implement it in a scrollviewer. I have disabled the browsers scrollbars so I can use mine. And I need to set the scrollviewers height to fit the form...

Comment: The height is not an inherent property of a class. The height is the result of applying the class properties to an object, using the available space, under application of the degrees of freedom available.

Comment: I still need to get it's height though since I want to implement it in a scrollviewer. I have disabled the browsers scrollbars so I can use mine. And I need to set the scrollviewers height to fit the form...

Comment: @JohnP. HTML Agility Pack can't run javascript, thus it cannot interact with any DOM elements and get any elements run-time attributes like `height`. To do that, you need a headless browser like Watin or Selenium. If you're interesting, I can help you and provide a Watin C# solution and do what you want.

Comment: @ChristosLytras of course I am interested. And thank you for being around.

Comment: @JohnP. please check my answer to see if the solution fits for your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a solution using the headless browser Watin to get the height of a DOM element using inline javascript.

First install *Watin* using *Visual Studio Nuget Package Manager Console* by executing:

```
PM> Install-Package WatiN
```

After the successfull installation of Watin headless browser, you can use it like this to navigate to a page and run a simple javascript to retrieve an element's height:

```
using WatiN.Core;
...

private void buttonGetElementHeight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WatiN.Core.Settings.Instance.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;
    IE browser = new IE();

    browser.GoToNoWait("https://m.investing.com/economic-calendar/");
    browser.WaitUntilContainsText("Filters");

    var height = browser.Eval("document.getElementsByClassName('js-economic-calendar')[0].offsetHeight");
    labelResult.Text = String.Format("Element height is {0}px", height);

    browser.ForceClose();
}
```

Here is a screen capture of the working button fetching the height:

[image: Screen capture]

**EDIT**

Beware that this is a test and you have to implement some error handling for both *C# Watin objects* and *inline javascript* that is being evaluated.

**UPDATE**

Here is how to do it using `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView`:

```
private async void webView1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var offsetHeight = await webView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] {
        "document.getElementsByClassName('js-economic-calendar')[0].offsetHeight.toString()"
    });
    textBox.Text = offsetHeight;
}

private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    webView1.LoadCompleted += webView1_LoadCompleted;
    webView1.Navigate(new Uri("https://m.investing.com/economic-calendar/"));
}
```

My working screen capture:

[image: WebView Screen Capture]

Comment: Watin is not supported on UWP.

Comment: @JohnP. You mention nowhere in your question nor comments, that you need the solution to work on UWP. How did you find out that it's not working on UWP?

Comment: I actually had tagged it. It was edited by someone and removed. Will update that. Sorry for the troubles.

Comment: Now understanding a bit your script and trying to implement it to the `WebView` in C# I think it could be used like this `var content = await Browser.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementsByClassName('js-economic-calendar')[0].offsetHeight" });`
However I am get nothing...

Comment: Do you want to test a **Selenium** approach using **PhantomJS** headless browser?

Comment: You are talking to me for things I am not even aware of. The only one I was aware of a bit was Selenium but never tried it. Still is not available on UWP. I want to test everything that's going to give me a solution...

Comment: However I believe the above C# code should do the same as your code. Logically...

Comment: Well, PhantomJS is a headless browser. A headless browser is a browser program that has no visual window and it can open sites and provide everything that a usual visual browser has, like rendered DOM elements, running javascript, frames, just like you had the URI opened inside a browser. How you know PhantomJS isn't working on universal windows platforms? It's an `.exe` program that is linked with a .NET package.

Comment: PhantomJs works, Selenium can't be added. However I just gave a shot to PhantomJs. It actually does the work I believe even if I didn't get there exactly but I don't want to add third party .exe to my project.

Comment: Damn, I didn't think I have to convert it to string to be able to get it. I knew I was not far away. Good job mate. Just one thing, the object I am should get to get the correct height is `boxItem calendar`. Very well done. You deserve those 50 point and even more.
Euxaristw

Comment: Yes, I thought it should be converted to string so the `InvokeScriptAsync` do not have any conversion issues and it worked. Also it needs to be done inside `LoadCompleted` event to have the full page loaded. I'm glad my question was helpful. Parakalo! (You're welcome!)

Comment: Hey Christos, looking back to this, maybe you could help me here since it has to do with exactly the same site and for sure with java:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308108/get-html-source-code-of-table-with-specific-attribute

Comment: As explained to the thread, I want to change the time from the combobox so I can have the news with my current GMT time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, as the height is calculated by the browser.

you would have to prerender this type of HTML first then calculate it.

---

Update: 
If you are willing to get the height using JavaScript, then its easy.

Get the div that is wrapping your view that you want to use your slimscroll

```
function getsize() {
            var el = $('#divIdYouWantSize'),
//current eight of your div
               curHeight = el.height(),
//set div height using CSS style
               autoHeight = el.css('height', $(window).height() ).height();
//try animating the resize so it looks pretty
                el.height(curHeight).animate({ height: autoHeight }, 100);
};
```

Comment: How about getting the number of articles and then multiply it by their height?

Comment: you would still have to know the height of the "article" div

Comment: If you check the image above, you will see that I can find it's height through the browser. Is there a way to get that programmatically?

Comment: The height of each article is 63

Comment: I'm sorry. What you are looking for cannot be done server side unless you render it on the server first.

Comment: If you want to get the height client side, use JavaScript and object.height

Comment: If you check its style, it also hasn't set fixed height. So the div just use default height value "Auto". it's actual height will be rendered by current browser. If you try to use `var height = News.Attributes["height"].Value;` to get its height, you will get exception. It's because there's no height attribute in it. For your case, I think you don't need to care about it. Because the original web page hasn't cared about its height. It means that height value will not affect its layout. In your app, you just could set a appropriate height value for it.

Comment: I don't care how it can be done to be honest. The reason I need it's height is because I have disabled the webview's scrollbars and embedded into a ScrollViewer. I am using scrollviewers scrollbars to scroll through the website. The reason for this is because the only thing I need visible there is that form.
I see marc is pointing that I need to render it to the server and then get it's size. How is that possible programmatically since I don't even know what it means?

Comment: Yes u can render it. However based on your explanation I don't think you need to get the size in c#. Can you use JavaScript? If so I have a solution for you

Comment: Added a function that gets the height using JavaScript Jquery.

Comment: And how could that be used in C#? I am very bad in handling browsers...
Acutally in C# we use `var height = News.Attributes["height"].Value;` to get the height attribute but in this case it doesn't work.